# WPF Ellipses clipping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ellipse

i'm having an issue with ellipse objects clipping when the size reaches a certain threshold.  I've been fighting it for a couple of hours and can't seem to figure out the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the XAML code for the ellipse below:

```
        <Ellipse Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="0,13,1,13" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.875">
            <Ellipse.Height>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <converters:DivisionMultiConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding ElementName="CircleSpinner" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                    <Binding Source="3.65"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Ellipse.Height>
            <Ellipse.Width>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <converters:DivisionMultiConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                    <Binding Source="1.25"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Ellipse.Width>
            <Ellipse.Stroke>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.8"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Stroke>
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
```

[image: Ellipse clipping issue.]

[image: Actual control without clipping issue.]

Comment: Are you just trying to make a busy indicator dude? What's with all the converters, transforms, and margins?

Comment: @ChrisW. It doesn't really matter what I'm trying to do, but yes, that is what i'm doing.  Converters are for making it a sizable busy indicator, transforms are for angling the ellipses, margins are for.. margins?...

I'm not looking for advice on anything other than why the ellipses are clipping, thank you though.

Comment: Everything I just inquired about IS what's causing your clipping amigo. If I have time later I'll swing back but it's a busy day and I leave soon for a long weekend. PS, you are looking for advice, or you wouldn't have asked your question. Cheers ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. Not a problem, i edited the original post with a gif of what the final outcome is at the moment when sized so no clipping occurs.  I can see that the binding adds a layer of complexity and that could be causing the clipping, but the reason/fix to why that is happening is alluding me completely right now.  I'll probably take a break from it and come back at some point later.

Regards.

Comment: Oh hey that's pretty cool, now I get what you were trying to do. At first it didn't make a lot of sense but I got ya now. Sorry I had to disappear on ya but glad you found a remedy! Looks neat man.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer if anyone looks at this in the future.

It was a margin issue.  When the size of the control reached a certain size (smaller) the margins began clipping the ellipses.  Removed margins where necessary and it is now behaving as expected.